# how can I stop appendchild from making subchilds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one span that contain a button when you click it button disappear and the span appear and show this text "wait..."
Im doing this with appendchild, so i write a code for it to stop appending new childs, the script is fine and worked but something else happen...
when i click on the button it disappear and the text appear but the LogIn wont happen anymore.
here's the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enterSystem() {
            document.getElementById("btnLogin").style.display = 'none';
            var span = document.getElementById('brain13');
            while ( span.firstChild ) {
               span.removeChild(span.firstChild);
            }
            span.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Wait...") );    
        }
    </script>
```

HTML SIDE:

```
<span id="brain13" onclick="enterSystem();">
   <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_click" />
</span>
```

the problem is that onclick for the button"btnLogin_click" stop working.
thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we could see, and work with? Also, that's not HTML; that's [tag:asp] (that generates the HTML).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your page initially hides the login button and the text. End of story? Is there any relevant information missing in the question?

Comment: sorry guys i forgot about the function part...the function is exist but it still wont work.

Comment: @ Frederik.L the text appear after clicking the button,but the button wont work for Login part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the span gets the click event first, and given that your login button is inside it, he gets removed before he can handle it. Try putting your login button outside the span.

Also, while jQuery is tagged, I assume we can do some logical abstraction with something like this:

```
$('#brain13').click(function(){
    $('#btnLogin').hide();
    $(this).html('<p>Waiting...</p>');
});
```

See this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XKKhb/).

Comment: it works and the button disappear but this '<p>Waiting...</p>' doesn't appear.

Comment: is there anyway that i can say if the value already exist stop appending and start the btnLogin???

Answer (score 0):

your chunck of code works on document load i.e. first time the page is loaded, you should be writing that in a function and calling that function wherever or whenever you want to remove child